# Ruby on Rails Tutorial, chapter 8 rspec errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm following the tutorial by Michael Hartl. I started chapter 8 and can't figure out what step I missed to get failures. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

```
    Failures:

  1) User pages signup with invalid information should not create a user
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_shared__error_messages_html_erb___725910499_85961520'
     # ./app/views/users/new.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_users_new_html_erb___744286408_86222100'
     # ./app/views/users/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___744286408_86222100'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23:in `create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:30:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:30:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages signup with invalid information after submission 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button submit }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_shared__error_messages_html_erb___725910499_85961520'
     # ./app/views/users/new.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_users_new_html_erb___744286408_86222100'
     # ./app/views/users/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___744286408_86222100'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23:in `create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:33:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User pages signup with invalid information after submission 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button submit }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_shared__error_messages_html_erb___725910499_85961520'
     # ./app/views/users/new.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_users_new_html_erb___744286408_86222100'
     # ./app/views/users/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___744286408_86222100'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23:in `create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:33:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

---

## users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @title = "Sign up"
    @user = User.new

        respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  def create 
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

---

## user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } 
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
      describe "after submission" do
        before { click_button submit }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",           with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",          with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",       with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation",   with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

## app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")%>
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @users.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the tutorial (if it's online)? We don't know what is chapter 8 of Michael Hartl's tutorial unless you provide a link or a quote.

Comment: Marek Lipka is correct! I was only focusing on _error_messages.html.erb and couldn't figure out why it was nil and giving me rspec failures. I changed users to user and now everything is great! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `@users` in your `_error_messages.html.erb`, which is `nil`, you should have `@user`.

```
<% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li>* <%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been staring at this on and off all day and could not see it.